# "Malformed input around byte" when uploading an image

Tags: liferay

When i upload images and publish pages, it shows a message **web content is temporarily unavailable**.

This is the error in the log:

```
21:28:57,687 ERROR [http-bio-2020-exec-6][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 714
    at com.liferay.portal.image.ImageToolImpl.read(ImageToolImpl.java:446)
    at com.liferay.portal.image.ImageToolImpl.getImage(ImageToolImpl.java:368)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.image.ImageToolUtil.getImage(ImageToolUtil.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ImageLocalServiceImpl.updateImage(ImageLocalServiceImpl.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
21:30:20,989 WARN  [http-bio-2020-exec-3][code_jsp:?] {code="404", msg="/ONA-theme/images/common/edit_white.png", uri=/ONA-theme/images/common/edit_white.png}
21:30:20,990 WARN  [http-bio-2020-exec-10][code_jsp:?] {code="404", msg="/ONA-theme/images/common/edit_template_white.png", uri=/ONA-theme/images/common/edit_template_white.png}
21:30:20,997 WARN  [http-bio-2020-exec-3][code_jsp:?] {code="404", msg="/ONA-theme/images/common/add_white.png", uri=/ONA-theme/images/common/add_white.png}
21:30:20,998 WARN  [http-bio-2020-exec-10][code_jsp:?] {code="404", msg="/ONA-theme/images/common/configuration_white.png", uri=/ONA-theme/images/common/configuration_white.png}
```

How can I successful upload an image?

Comment: What kind of image did you upload? And which version of Liferay are you using? He is complaining about the format of the image, so you should try a different image first.

Comment: In addition, there are quite a few 404 errors around images in your theme, which makes me wonder if you don't have a deeper problem with your theme. Please give some more information on your configuration, your theme and the way you build it. Also: When does this exception occur?

Comment: Sir , whenever i use png file then its not working and give this error, but when i upload jpg images ,then its work fine,... can you tell me reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the type of the image is causing the issue.
On Linux/Mac system try to use (by shell/temrinal)

```
# file filepath/filename
```

A common issue is that you are using CMYK and not RGB colorspace (try to open the image with a software like Photoshop and verify/convert your image).

Comment: Sir , whenever i use png file then its not working and give this error, but when i upload jpg images ,then its work fine,...
can you tell me reason behind this.

Comment: As I wrote, I think you should check the kind of your image... for example did you verify the colorspace of your png? If you aren't comfortable to proceed in this way try to use this PNG file: http://www.personal.psu.edu/sdh5174/Mario_png.png (I just verified its colorspace and it is RGB and not CMYK). Let me know...